# Where to put logback.xml in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, configuration, logback

Where to put the *logback.xml* file in Tomcat when we want to have it configurable?

And how to make it accessible for the Java application(s) running inside?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You typically want to have `logback.xml` on the classpath. Per the [Logback FAQ](http://logback.qos.ch/faq.html#configFileLocation):

> For web-applications, configuration files can be placed directly under WEB-INF/classes/.

You therefore need to put it in:

```
/webapps/your-app/WEB-INF/classes/
```

Logback has some conventions for where it looks for it. [Those are documented here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

> - Logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
> - If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called logback-test.xml in the classpath.
> - If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath..
> - If neither file is found, logback configures itself automatically using the BasicConfigurator which will cause logging output to be
>     directed to the console.

But you can also tell it where to find the file.

> You may specify the location of the default configuration file with a
>   system property named "logback.configurationFile". The value of this
>   property can be a URL, a resource on the class path or a path to a
>   file external to the application.
>
> ```
> java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1
> ```
>
> Note that the file extension must be ".xml" or ".groovy". Other
>   extensions are ignored. Explicitly registering a status listener may
>   help debugging issues locating the configuration file.

Comment: Is it better to have it *inside* my webapp, or somewhere else where it can be shared between applications?

Comment: @Harold That's up to you and your setup. You might want a different configuration for each webapp.