# upgrade from tomcat 7 to tomcat8.5.41 deploy fail

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat8.5

I changed from tomcat7 to tomcate8.5.41 
when deploy my application on it it fails 
[java code for login bean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCVvy.png)

exception thrown in this line

```
private static Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginBean.class);
```

I use primefaces 7  jsf 2.2.6

I think one of the reasons is due to the logging module

I tried to add the following dependency and also not working

I tried to add the log dependency and also not working

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
     <version>1.7.25</version> 
 </dependency> 

INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mySharedData/Mokalmat/WorkSpaces/EclipseWorkSpace/VAS_prime_7_ws/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConfigurationWebTool/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mySharedData/Mokalmat/WorkSpaces/EclipseWorkSpace/VAS_prime_7_ws/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConfigurationWebTool/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
    SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
    Jun 12, 2019 3:02:57 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
    SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
    com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:508)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:402)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:340)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:504)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
        at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:325)
        at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.processClassList(AnnotationScanner.java:309)
        at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:128)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DelegatingAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java:85)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:932)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:884)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:383)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
        at com.vis.vasplatform.web.configuration.beans.LoginBean.<clinit>(LoginBean.java:42)
        ... 20 more

Jun 12, 2019 3:02:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:508)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:340)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:504)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.processClassList(AnnotationScanner.java:309)
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:128)
    at com.sun.faces.config.DelegatingAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:932)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:884)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:383)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
    at com.vis.vasplatform.web.configuration.beans.LoginBean.<clinit>(LoginBean.java:42)
    ... 20 more

.......




Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5474)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I tried to add the following dependency and also not working

 <dependency> -->
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
     <version>1.7.25</version> 
 </dependency> 

INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mySharedData/Mokalmat/WorkSpaces/EclipseWorkSpace/VAS_prime_7_ws/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConfigurationWebTool/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mySharedData/Mokalmat/WorkSpaces/EclipseWorkSpace/VAS_prime_7_ws/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConfigurationWebTool/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Jun 12, 2019 3:02:57 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:508)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:340)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:504)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.processClassList(AnnotationScanner.java:309)
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:128)
    at com.sun.faces.config.DelegatingAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:932)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:884)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:383)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
    at com.vis.vasplatform.web.configuration.beans.LoginBean.<clinit>(LoginBean.java:42)
    ... 20 more

Jun 12, 2019 3:02:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:508)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:340)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:504)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.processClassList(AnnotationScanner.java:309)
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:128)
    at com.sun.faces.config.DelegatingAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:932)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:884)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:383)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
    at com.vis.vasplatform.web.configuration.beans.LoginBean.<clinit>(LoginBean.java:42)
    ... 20 more

.......


SEVERE: Unable to load annotated class: com.vis.vasplatform.web.configuration.beans.LoginBean, reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.vis.vasplatform.web.configuration.beans.LoginBean
Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:261)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:146)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(FacesContext.java:897)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.getApplicationFactoryManager(FactoryFinder.java:798)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.getApplicationFactoryManager(FactoryFinder.java:793)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.access$100(FactoryFinder.java:768)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:377)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)


Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:261)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:146)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(FacesContext.java:897)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.getApplicationFactoryManager(FactoryFinder.java:798)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.getApplicationFactoryManager(FactoryFinder.java:793)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.access$100(FactoryFinder.java:768)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:377)




Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ConfigurationWebTool] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.isPackageProtectionEnabled(SecurityUtil.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getAttribute(ApplicationContextFacade.java:375)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext.getAttribute(StandardContext.java:6599)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ApplicationMap.get(ApplicationMap.java:97)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCacheKey.<init>(FactoryFinder.java:939)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.getApplicationFactoryManager(FactoryFinder.java:801)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.getApplicationFactoryManager(FactoryFinder.java:793)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManagerCache.access$100(FactoryFinder.java:768)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:377)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)

.......

Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
Jun 12, 2019 3:02:59 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5474)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is `com.vis.vasplatform.web.configuration.beans.LoginBean` your code or a 3rd-party library?  Because it looks like it has been implemented to use Logback directly, and something is attempting to pass it a sl4fj Logger.

Comment: Changing dependencies won't fix this.  It is a deeper problem.  You will need to change you code and / or your deployed configs.  Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427307/where-to-put-logback-xml-in-tomcat

Comment: yes, LoginBean  Is my code

Comment: Well perhaps you should show us the relevant part; i.e. where the `ClassCastException` is being thrown.

Comment: Here is the imports @StephenC

 import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

Comment: @ManagedBean(name = "LoginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
private static Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginBean.class);
public String login() {
String forwardPage = "";

// here ex thrown
logger.debug(LogUtils.getLoggingParamForm(LoggingEnum.CLASS, className) LogUtils.getLoggingParamForm(LoggingEnum.LOGGED_USER, username) + LogUtils.getLoggingParamForm(LoggingEnum.MESSAGE,"Starting login method"));

Comment: Please put your code in your question.  It is unreadable in the comments.  Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56562644/edit) button.

Comment: @StephenC check attached image for the code, thanks :)

Comment: No.  Don't attach it.  Copy and paste the code into the question, and format it.  (It is not rocket science ...)   And read this to understand why we are insistent about this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code.  And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the presence of two conflicted implementations of slf4j. (see line 2 of the log)

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

The two implementation are shown in log  :

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [.../slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:.../logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

In your project you can run the 
 `mvn dependency:tree` command and exclude slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following lines of your `LoginBean` class

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

...

private static Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginBean.class);
```

The `Logger` class is a "logback" class.

The `LoggerFactory` class is an "slf4j" class.

The `getLogger` method returns an instance of some class that implements `org.slf4j.Logger` not `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger`.  You can't use a type cast here because the two classes are unrelated.

You can't mix slf4j and logback like this.  You need to choose between using the slf4j APIs or the logback APIs in your code.

I don't know which to recommend because the small amount of code that you have shared does not explain why you have chosen to declared `logger` as a logback `Logger`.

But either way, the problem that is causing the `ClassCastException`s is in your code, not in Tomcat or your servlet configs.  There may also be other problems (e.g. multiple slf4j logging providers at runtime) but *this* one is a show stopper.

Comment: But logback Logger is also an implementation of SLF4J API. I think the source of probleme is that the slf4j-simple implementation is chosen at runtime.